# select top from ordered query into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a new table using the results of a query but I am getting a syntax error at the end of the query. Here is the query:

```
select *
into new_table
from
(select top(1455) * from tbl_patients_problems_to_snomed_buckets_2014
where SnoMedScui not in 
(select SnoMedScui from groups_first_round)
order by GroupName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subquery in FROM clause must have an alias

```
select top 1455 *
into new_table
from tbl_patients_problems_to_snomed_buckets_2014
where SnoMedScui not in (select SnoMedScui from groups_first_round)
order by GroupName
```

Comment: Because you always need to name the from subquery. I name it as A.

Comment: Not to mention you dont need a subquery.
 `select top (1455) * INTO new_table 
   from tbl_patients_problems_to_snomed_buckets_2014
   where SnoMedScui not in 
      (select SnoMedScui from groups_first_round)
   order by GroupName`

Comment: For sure, I answered fast and didn´t pay attention to this. Thanks @Blim

Comment: Correction `derived table` not `subquery`,  my mistake :P

Comment: Here a good discussion about the difference of the terms http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/26/sql-subqueries-and-derived-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries in a from clause need an alias:

```
select *
into new_table
from
    (select top(1455) * 
    from tbl_patients_problems_to_snomed_buckets_2014
    where SnoMedScui not in 
        (select SnoMedScui from groups_first_round)
    order by GroupName
    ) MyTableAlias
```